# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' ... Too many zip entries 236220 (MAX=65535)

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I'm executing cordova build -d but keep getting this error at 94% complete:

[Here's a screenshot of the MacOs terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIpTU.png)

Here's a partial transcription of the screenshot:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > Too many zip entries 236220 (MAX=65535)
```

I haven't been able to find any info about this online. Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve?
I tried gradle clean then gradle build, increasing org.gradle.jvmargs size, and updating from gradle 7.6 to 8.

Comment: ... does your package have a lot of resource files?

Comment: You have way too many files... 236220 ? why??

Comment: @starball I shouldn't have that many resource files. cordova build finishes the prepare process successfully

Comment: @Eric I have not idea where all the zip files are coming from. it doesn't say. the only zip file I am aware of comes from the distribution url: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip

Comment: You don't understand. A apk or abb file is a zip file. The 236220 files are the files in your project, not zip files

Comment: @Eric I don't see any apk or abb files in my project. do you know what determines the zip entries max size?

Comment: .apk or .abb file, is the final file once your app is compiled. When you "build", you generate that file from all the files in your project.

Comment: @Eric I understand now. thank you for the info. do you know how to increase the max size?

Comment: You can't, besides you shouldn't have 236220 files in a mobile app. Here is your issue.